# iOS LaunchScreen File with iPad Pro not working

Tags: ios, ipad, autolayout

I am using a Launch Screen File but i am still getting weird frame issues when running app on iPad Pro. My understanding was that using a Launch Screen file will tell the app that we are optimizing for iPad Pro and the storyboard with proper constraints will adjust the views accordingly but it is not.. any help would be greatly appreciated on this matter. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Can you post the launch screen file or a snapshot?

Comment: Can you post constraint snap..??

Comment: need to described constraints here so its helpful. So please show constraint which u set?

Comment: the constraints are setup properly (top, bottom, leading, trailing) to superview set to a constant of 0

Answer (score 1):

Just set 0 from All side(Superview) to Subview ,

```
Leading from superiew=0 , 

Trialing from superview=0 , 

Top=0 , 

Bottom=0
```

Check this ,

[image]

I hope your problem will be solved.

Comment: the constraints are setup properly (top, bottom, leading, trailing) to superview set to a constant of 0

Comment: can you please post the pic of constrain or if possible attach Lunchscreenfile.